# Is there a way in Kotlin for an interface to have an associated type contract?

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Swift you can write something like:

```swift
protocol Constants {
    associatedtype StringProperties
}

struct ViewState {
    let viewName: String
}

extension ViewState: Constants {

    enum StringProperties: String {
        case text = "some view text"
    }

}

struct LayerState {
    let layerName: String
}

extension LayerState: Constants {

    enum StringProperties: String {
        case text = "some layer text"
    }
}

let viewState = ViewState(viewName: "Some view name")
let viewValue = ViewState.StringProperties.text.rawValue // "some view text"

let layerState = LayerState(layerName: "Some layer name")
let layerValue = LayerState.StringProperties.text.rawValue // "some layer text"
```

In this way if a struct or class conforms to protocol `Constants` it has to implement something pertaining to `StringConstants`

Is there something like this in `Kotlin` which forces this kind of conformance from an interface?

It would be ideal to do something like:

```
interface Constants {
    enum class StringProperties 
}

data class ViewState(val viewName: String): Constants {

    enum class StringProperties(val string: String) {
        Text("some view text")
    }

}

data class LayerState(val layerName: String): Constants {

    enum class StringProperties(val string: String) {
        Text("some layer text")
    }

}

val viewState = ViewState("some view name")
val viewText = ViewState.StringProperties.Text.string // "some view text"

val layerState = LayerState("some layer name")
val layerText = LayerState.StringProperties.Text.string // "some layer text"
```

Comment: Why do you want an enum based getter instead of regular  fun-based getter that would work in Kotlin?

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin (as well as in Java) enums are defined at compile time as singletons. That's why you can't use variables on them. Only predefined static values.

In you have this enum

```
enum class MyEnum(val text: String) {
    MyValue("some text")
}
```

And you call it

```
val myEnum = MyEnum.MyValue
```

Each time you will have the same object.

All enums that are declared inside other classes are [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) ([here is the question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) about static keyword), which means they don't depend on objects at runtime but on classes at compile time.

```
data class MyClass {
   enum class MyEnum {
       ...
   }
}
```

Will compile to:

```java
public class MyClass {

   public static enum MyEnum {
      ...
   }
}
```

This is why you can't use [inner](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) modifier on them:

[image: inner enum class is not allowed]

To achieve your desired result you have two options:

1) Use properties:

```
interface Constants {
   val text: String
}

// data classes are final and cannot be extended later
data class ViewState(val viewName: String) : Constants {
    override val text = "some view text"
}

data class LayerState(val layerName: String) : Constants {
    override val text = "some layer text"
}
```

2) Define two different enums (without interface):

```
data class ViewState(val viewName: String) {
    enum class StringProperties(val string: String) {
        Text("some view text")
    }
}

data class LayerState(val layerName: String) {
    enum class StringProperties(val string: String) {
        Text("some layer text")
    }
}
```

This way you can use it "as is" but without your `Constants` interface

```
val viewText = ViewState.StringProperties.Text.string // "some view text"
val layerText = LayerState.StringProperties.Text.string // "some layer text"
```

**Edit:**

Kotlin supports [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) but it doesn't modify your class. Instead new method with your object as argument is created:

```
fun MyObject.extensionFunc() {
   // do stuff
}
```

Will compile to

```java
public void extensionFunc(MyObject $receiver) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I stumbled upon your question again, thought it through again, and I think I have a solution for you: how `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` are tied together in `RecyclerView` android lib.

```
interface Adapter<T : Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    fun doSmth(viewHolder: T)

    interface ViewHolder
}
```

Whenever you want to implement `Adapter` you must also implement `ViewHolder`:

```
class AdapterImpl : Adapter<AdapterImpl.MyViewHolder> {

    override fun doSmth(viewHolder: MyViewHolder) {
    }

    class MyViewHolder : Adapter.ViewHolder {
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you're been looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is a very very basic use case you've presented there is a specific reason why I am writing a contract of `Constants` in `Swift` because I lumsum different value types together check if they conform to `Constants` and pull out their registered constant enum identifier

Comment: Post some code on how exactly you use it. Because from what you say I think the first  option should work for you: ```listOfYourObjects.mapNonNull { it as? Constants }.forEach { val name = it.text }```

Comment: @SwiftyKotlin I added alternative answer. Please see at `Edit 2`. Just for the sake of argument look at it, because I'm curious if I understood your question correctly.